# node express no data getting to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Have looked for similar questions and can't find anything on this, so apologies if it already exists.

I'm pretty new to front-end work so I've got a fairly simple personal project on the go. I've got a pretty basic node/express setup and am trying to initiate a GET request to the `/next-user` URL

the GET is set up in the server as:

```
app.get('/next-user', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

I know a common issue with this is that the body-parser module is not setup, so here is my setup code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

and the request is setup like;

```
    var data = {name:"HelloServerWorld"};
    console.log(data)
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8081/next-user", data, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The server always echos an empty JSON object regardless of what I send to it where the client can see that the object is populated. I didn't want to post the entirety of the code but if it's needed then let me know, but I'm fairly confident the problem lies in what I've given so far, I'm just not sure where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests don't include "req.body", req.body is used with POST requests. You may want to pass data in the form of a parameter, e.g. " "/next-user/:id" or using a POST request instead to pass over the data!

Comment: Thanks so much, that got it working, feel like an idiot now. Do you have a more specific example of using the url parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `console.log` with `res.end` and you should get back the request.